# API call working with `curl` does not work in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am getting a json file back from a http request:

```
[
  {
    "_ref": "Ref0",
    "name": "someName0"
  },
  {
    "_ref": "Ref1",
    "name": "someName1"
  },
  {
    "_ref": "Ref2",
    "name": "someName2"
  }
]
```

Here's my swift code so far:

```swift
guard let natRules = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
  with: data, options: []) as? [Any] 
  else { return }
```

How can I get the array's item's content as a `[String:String]` dictionary? When I print `natRules`, the result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_ref" = "Ref0";
    "name" = "someName0"
  },
  {
    "_ref" = "Ref1";
    "name" = "someName1"
  },
  {
    "_ref" = "Ref2";
    "name" = "someName2"
  }
]
```

I would expect the entries to look like `"_ref": "Ref0" ...` though...
What am I missing here?

**Edit (and message to future me):**

Seems as though with the above sample I gave, I didn't account for non-string values (which are present in the code I am trying to handle) -- so basically, if there are non-string values present, a cast to `[[String:Any]]` is necessary.
So that's my TIL I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if the result is supposed to be `[[String:String]]` cast is accordingly

```
guard let natRules = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
  with: data) as? [[String:String]]
  else { return }
```

To iterate over an array use a loop

```
for rule in natRules {
     print(rule)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me -- the cast to `[[String:String]]` fails and the `guard let` returns (proven by a print-stmt I added prior to the return...

Comment: Then you didn't post the real JSON. The JSON in the question is clearly `[[String:String]]`

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right... I tried to give a sample of the JSON but didn't account for non-string values that are present as well... So, with my sample given, you are absolutely correct!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast from `[Any]` to `[[String: String]]`

```
var result = [[String: String]]()
do {
   if let natRules = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
    with: data, options: []) as? [[String: String]] {
    result = natRules
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I failed to give an accurate example (see my edit above). As vadian was faster than you, I chose his answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to give an accurate enough sample of my json repsonse -- if there are key / value pairs with non-string values, a cast to `[[String:Any]]` is necessary:

```swift
guard let natRules = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
  with: data, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] 
  else { return }
```

Thanks for all the valuable answers.